# Solving for vector from equations. Can Dot product product be bought down as the denominator

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, projective-geometry

I am new to vector geometry. I have a set of two equations:-

$p_2 \cdot x = (p_3 - \bar{p}) \cdot b_1$

$p_2 \cdot y = (p_3 - \bar{p}) \cdot b_2$

where, $p_2(x,y)$ is a 2D vector, $p_3(x,y,z)$ is a 3D vector, $b_1$, $b_2$ are also 3D. Now given that I know $p_2$, $b_1$, $b_2$, $\bar{p}$. Can we find out $p_3$ using the above equations. If so how?

I bought the $b_1$ to the denominator as we do in scalar equations, but I don't really think that it works.

Comment: If you are working in $\mathbb{R}^3$, you can't mix in vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (except as considering them as vectors with component 0 in the $z$ coordinate). And no, you can't divide by a vector in a scalar product. It also isn't clear what your $p_2 \cdot x$ means (p_2.x in the original), do you mean the $x$ component of $p_2$? If so, your equations give the components directly.

Comment: yes p_x refers to the x component in p2.

Comment: But what do you mean by "they give the components directly".

Answer (score 1):

You essentially have two equations in three unknowns, for which there is not a unique solution. If $p_3=(x,y,z)$ then since $\bar{p}$ and $b_2$ are known, even if both expressions involving 2d vectors on the left sides compute to known numbers, you can only get so far as
$$[1] \ \ p_3 \cdot b_1=k_1,\ \ p_3 \cdot b_2=k_2,$$
where $k_1=p_2.x+\bar{p}\cdot b_1$ and $k_2=p_2.y + \bar{p}\cdot b_2.$ It is unclear (to me) just what $p_2.x$ and $p_2.y$ mean, and whether $x,y$ denote two dimensional vectors which are known. But the point is, whatever they denote, if their values are known real numbers then $k_1,k_2$ are just two real numbers, and then replacing $p_3$ by its unknown coordinates $(x,y,z)$ and replacing $b_1,b_2$ by whatever numerical coordinates they have, the system [1] ends up as two linear equations in the three unknowns $x,y,z$. But two linear equations in three unknowns are never enough to determine the values of those unknowns.

Comment: in p_2.x, x refers to the x component of p_2,similarly for y also the same.

Comment: Then $p_2.x$ and $p_2.y$ are known real numbers, and my argument is valid, showing why one cannot determine the coordinates of $p_3$ from the known quantities. Because whatever these coordinates of $p_2$ might be, they only contribute to the constants $k_1$ and $k_2$, making these specific reals, and then the system [1] is two linear equations in three unknowns, as stated.